# force_ssl on a Rails 4 app with nginx + unicorn gives a 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, unicorn

**My setup:**

1. Rails 4 app on AWS.
2. Running nginx + unicorn

I would like to have all actions in a controller accessed via https. so I did the following:

1. Added force_ssl to that controller.
2. scp'ed the key and cert to /etc/ssl/ on the AWS host. This key/cert was generated by AWS. Changed the owner of both those files to 'deployer' (which is the user that runs nginx/unicorn, I think).
3. Added the following to my nginx.conf:

```
    server {
      listen 443;
      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.cer;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.cer;

      root /path/to/public;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
      location @unicorn {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
      }

      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 10;

    }
```

Most of these instructions are from: http://seaneshbaugh.com/posts/configuring-nginx-and-unicorn-for-force_ssl

Now, when I go to http://example.com/my_ssl_controller/action it redirects me to https://example.com/my_ssl_controller/action, which then renders a 503 "Service Temporarily Unavailable" error.

1. Do I need to make some changes to the boxes from the AWS dashboard? (Eg, open port 443).
2. Is there any other config to change on the host outside of the rails app?

Thanks for all the help with this!

Comment: 1. Sure. You can check is the port is accesible: `telnet IP 443` from your local host.

Comment: I did telnet hostIP 443 as well as telnet load-balancerIP 443, and both got connected. So they are reachable. What else could it be?